# My output is suppose to align on the $ like my professors. However I'm not sure how to use setw()

Tags: c++, alignment, output-formatting

My output isn't aligning on $

I tried cout << left << setw(1) on all of my cout

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // insert code here...

    float RENT_OR_MORTGAGE;
    float UTILITIES;
    float PHONE;
    float CABLE;
    // H stands for housing
    float TOTAL_MONTHLY_HOUSING_COSTS;
    float TOTAL_ANNUAL_HOUSEING_COSTS;
    char dollars = '$';

    cout << "Enter your monthly costs for the following: " << endl << endl;

    cout << "Rent or Mortgage: ";
    cin >> dollars >> RENT_OR_MORTGAGE;

    cout << "Utilities: " << setw(10) << left;
    cin  >> dollars >> UTILITIES;

    cout << "Phone(s): " << setw(10) << left;
    cin  >> dollars >> PHONE;

    cout << "Cable: " << setw(10) << left;
    cin  >> dollars >> CABLE;

    TOTAL_MONTHLY_HOUSING_COSTS = RENT_OR_MORTGAGE + UTILITIES + PHONE + CABLE;
    TOTAL_ANNUAL_HOUSEING_COSTS = (RENT_OR_MORTGAGE + UTILITIES + PHONE + CABLE) * 12;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(dollars) << left << "Total monthly housing costs: "  << dollars << TOTAL_MONTHLY_HOUSING_COSTS << endl << setw(dollars) << left << "Total annual housing costs: " << dollars << TOTAL_ANNUAL_HOUSEING_COSTS << endl;

    return 0;




 I want an output of 


Enter your monthly costs for the following:

Rent or mortgage: $1348
Utilities: $215
Phone(s):  $99
Cable:     $69

Total monthly housing costs: $ 1731.00
Total annual housing costs:  $20772.00
```

```
my output is 


Enter your monthly costs for the following: 

Rent or Mortgage: $1348
Utilities: $512
Phone(s):  $99
Cable:     $69
Total monthly housing costs:        $2028.00
Total annual housing costs:         $24336.00
```

I want it to align on the $. I tried setw() and i would keep changing the number on the inside but nothing was changing. I have #include  but no changes. This is small project where I'm trying to match the correct outcome. Please share some advice, I'm looking forward to reading it.

Comment: While there's no "standard" about naming and symbols, all upper-case symbols are widely used for preprocessor macros or symbolic constants.

Comment: As for getting the dollar-signs aligned, just add spaces in your strings. Then the output of the sums, think about *where* you add the formatting. I also suggest you split the final output into two separate outputs. That will make it much easier to make sure they are aligned the same.

Comment: my output is actually

Comment: Enter your monthly costs for the following: 

Rent or Mortgage: $1348
Utilities: $215
Phone(s): $99
Cable: $69
Total monthly housing costs: $1731.00
Total annual housing costs: $20772.00

Comment: Please *edit your question* if you want to add information.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already pointed out, you can use spaces help achieve the format you want

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    float RENT_OR_MORTGAGE;
    float UTILITIES;
    float PHONE;
    float CABLE;
    // H stands for housing
    float TOTAL_MONTHLY_HOUSING_COSTS;
    float TOTAL_ANNUAL_HOUSEING_COSTS;

    cout << "Enter your monthly costs for the following: " << endl << endl;
    cout << "Rent or Mortgage: $";
    cin >> RENT_OR_MORTGAGE;

    cout << "Utilities: $";
    cin  >> UTILITIES;

    cout << "Phone(s):  $";
    cin  >> PHONE;

    cout << "Cable:     $";
    cin  >> CABLE;

    TOTAL_MONTHLY_HOUSING_COSTS = RENT_OR_MORTGAGE + UTILITIES + PHONE + CABLE;
    TOTAL_ANNUAL_HOUSEING_COSTS = (RENT_OR_MORTGAGE + UTILITIES + PHONE + CABLE) * 12;


    int digits = (TOTAL_ANNUAL_HOUSEING_COSTS * 100 / 100);
    cout << "Total monthly housing costs: $" << setw(to_string(digits).length() + 3) << fixed << right << setprecision(2) << TOTAL_MONTHLY_HOUSING_COSTS << endl;
    cout << "Total annual housing costs:  $" << setw(to_string(digits).length() + 3) << fixed << right << setprecision(2) << TOTAL_ANNUAL_HOUSEING_COSTS << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Enter your monthly costs for the following: 

Rent or Mortgage: $1348
Utilities: $215
Phone(s):  $99
Cable:     $69
Total monthly housing costs: $ 1731.00
Total annual housing costs:  $20772.00
```

Comment: How does you setw(to_string(digits).length() + 3) work?

Comment: I added 3 because of .00 that gets added from set precision.

Comment: How would I be able to type it using a float? I'm asking because I have a second assignment similar to this one.

Comment: +n + 1, where n is the amount of decimals and + 1 because of period added. Its pretty much the `setprecision` value + 1. Note that the decimals have to be `fixed`

Comment: so i set it alongside setpercision

Comment: and also why did you use digits instead of total annual housing costs?

Comment: but it has to be with int?

Comment: I used the total because it has more digits, so the monthly one will alight right with it. Not sure what you mean by has to be int.

Comment: you redefined total annual income as int digits; I was wondering how I could write it using floats such as float digits;

Comment: I made int ‘digits’ to get the number of digits in the number. ex. 7382 is 4 digits long, this is just one way to figure out the length.

Comment: Do you mind checking out my other post? i was trying to apply what you taught me to another problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776464/recite-and-tip-output-alignment-c-output-formatting/54776596#54776596