# recite and tip output alignment C++, output formatting

Tags: c++, output, output-formatting

I'm writing this code for my programming class and I got everything else to work however my output formatting isn't working out for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        double tip_fifteen;
        double tip_twenty;
        double tax;
        double bill;
        char dollars = '$';
        float meal_cost;

        cout << "Enter the meal cost: ";
        cin >> meal_cost;
        tip_twenty = meal_cost * .20;
        tip_fifteen = meal_cost * .15;
        tax = meal_cost * 0.0975;
        cout << "******************************************" << endl;

        //beginning outputs
        int digits;
        digits = meal_cost * 100 / 100;
        cout << setw(10) << left << "Meal Cost " << dollars;
        cout << setw(to_string(digits).length() + 3) << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << meal_cost << endl;

        cout << setw(10) << left << "Tax " << dollars;
        cout << setw(to_string(digits).length() + 3) << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << tax << endl;

        cout << setw(10) << left << "Tip (15%) " << dollars;
        cout << setw(to_string(digits).length() + 3) << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << tip_fifteen << endl;

        //tip outputs then final output statements
        cout << setw(10) << left << fixed << setprecision(2) << "Tip (20%) " << dollars << tip_twenty << endl;
        bill = tip_fifteen + meal_cost + tax;
        cout << "Your total bill is " << fixed << setprecision(2) << dollars << bill << " after 15% gratuity." << endl << "or" << endl;
        bill = tip_twenty + meal_cost + tax;
        cout << "Your total bill is " << fixed << setprecision(2) << dollars << bill << " after 20% gratuity." << endl;



return 0;
```

I want my output to look like this

```
Enter the meal cost: 56
******************************************
Meal Cost $ 56.00
Tax       $  5.46
Tip (15%) $  8.40
Tip (20%) $ 11.20
Your total bill is 69.86 after 15% gratuity.
or
Your total bill is 72.66 after 20% gratuity.
```

my output looks like this

```
Enter the meal cost: 56
******************************************
Meal Cost $56.00
Tax       $5.46 
Tip (15%) $8.40 
Tip (20%) $11.20
Your total bill is $69.86 after 15% gratuity.
or
Your total bill is $72.66 after 20% gratuity.
```

I'm having a problem using setw with floats however it's not working when i try to set the same variable as an int.
I've also tried using setw(25) to see if that would work somehow unfortunately it has not

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `right` if you want them aligned to the right, you also need to add a space " " after the `dollars`

```
cout << setw(10) << left << "Meal Cost " << dollars << " ";
cout << setw(to_string(digits).length() + 3) << fixed << right << showpoint << setprecision(2) << meal_cost << endl;
```

To this to all of the printed statements and you will get:

```
******************************************
Meal Cost $ 56.00
Tax       $  5.46
Tip (15%) $  8.40
Tip (20%) $ 11.20
```

Comment: Note to Asker: the code for  Tip (20%) does not match the code for the other outputs, so it will not render the same. Solution: Make it the same. The easiest way to do this is to write a function that does the formatting and is used by all of the related outputs. This also makes the program a bit shorter because there is less duplicated code. Duplication is nesting grounds for bugs.

Comment: What's different about "tip(20%)" I don't see how it doesn't match

Comment: @Brett: Tip 15: `cout << setw(10) << left << "Tip (15%) " << dollars << cout << setw(to_string(digits).length() + 3) << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << tip_fifteen << endl;`. Tip 20: `cout << setw(10) << left << fixed << setprecision(2) << "Tip (20%) " << dollars << tip_twenty << endl;` tip 20 much, much shorter than Tip 15. It leaves out some of the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

For there to be padding in the price column, `setw` has to be set to a large enough width.

For example:

```
std::cout << "$" << std::setw(10) << std::fixed
          << std::setprecision(2) << 56.0f << std::endl;
```

Prints:

```
$     56.00
```

Your code sets the width to:

```
std::to_string(digits).length() + 3
```

Which is only 5 characters, just enough to fit "56.00". For additional padding on the left you should increase the `setw` width.

Comment: but i want to alignment of numbers after the $

Comment: @Brett note how  the `<< left` earlier in the command was removed. Ultimately you need both `left` and a `right` to undo the `left`.